# Handle data after user paid with PayPal

Tags: php, api, paypal

I have a php that integrates a PayPal pay button. When the user presses it and pays successfully he gets redirected to a site. On this site how can I check that the user has paid? I want to have a functionality on my website where the user has to pay for.

So he sees the button, presses pay, pays, gets redirected, sees the site, types in his data, gets something to download. I thought about using the REST Api and look up a sale but for that I need the ID of the sale, which I don't have? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to implement something like this is to use [PayPal Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec).

1. User clicks pay button on your website.
2. Your site sends a `SetExpressCheckout` API request to PayPal to get checkout token and redirects user to checkout process on PayPal site.
3. PayPal takes user through checkout and then redirects them back to your site when they've paid with a `token` query string parameter appended to the URL.
4. Your site validates the token with PayPal and sends a `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` API request to PayPal to get the details of the transaction.
5. Your site sends a `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API request to PayPal to complete

See the PayPal developers site for [an introduction to the Express Checkout process](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) and [full documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).

I would also recommend you look at implementing [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/), which gives you near-instant feedback of transaction status.